# R - looking up strings and exclude based on other string

Tags: r

I could not find the answer how to count words in data frame and exclude if other word is found. 
I have got below df:

```
words <- c("INSTANCE find", "LA LA LA", "instance during",
           "instance", "instance", "instance", "find instance")

df <- data.frame(words)
df$words_count <- grepl("instance", df$words, ignore.case = T)
```

It counts all instances of **"instance"** I have been trying to exclude any row when word **find** is present as well.

I can add another grepl to look up for **"find"** and based on that exclude but I try to limit number of lines of my code.

Comment: Can you show us how your expected output should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a solution using a single regular expression, but you could do

```
df$words_count <- Reduce(`-`, lapply(c('instance', 'find'), grepl, df$words)) > 0
```

or

```
df$words_count <- Reduce(`&`, lapply(c('instance', '^((?!find).)*$'), grepl, df$words, perl = T, ignore.case = T))
```

This might be easier to read

```
library(tidyverse)
df$words_count <- c('instance', '^((?!find).)*$') %>% 
                    lapply(grepl, df$words, perl = T, ignore.case = T) %>%
                    reduce(`&`)
```

Comment: Thanks Renu. I use the first code and also added second word as a exclusion. Thanks again. My code now reads: `df$words_count <- Reduce(`&`, lapply(c('instance', '^((?!find).)*$', '^((?!during).)*$'), grepl, df$words, perl = T, ignore.case = T))`

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the number of times "instance" appears in a string, negating all in that string if "find" is found anywhere:

```
df$counts <- sapply(gregexpr("\\binstance\\b", words, ignore.case=TRUE), function(a) length(a[a>0])) *
  !grepl("\\bfind\\b", words, ignore.case=TRUE)
df
#             words counts
# 1   INSTANCE find      0
# 2        LA LA LA      0
# 3 instance during      1
# 4        instance      1
# 5        instance      1
# 6        instance      1
# 7   find instance      0
```

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. You can see from above that your code works for **find** but also counts **LA LA LA** as one.

Comment: Updated (didn't see that).

Comment: Thanks. Can you add another exclusion to your code? I tried to exlude any rows with word **during** and used below:`df$counts <- sapply(gregexpr("\\binstance\\b", words, ignore.case=TRUE), function(a) length(a[a>0])) *
  !grepl("\\bfind\\b", words, ignore.case=TRUE) *
  !grepl("\\bduring\\b", words, ignore.case=TRUE)` and `df$counts <- sapply(gregexpr("\\binstance\\b", words, ignore.case=TRUE), function(a) length(a[a>0])) *
  !grepl("\\bfind\\b", "\\bduring\\b", words, ignore.case=TRUE)` but with no luck.

Comment: I think you can update the second element to be `!grepl("\\b(find|during)\\b", words, ignore.case=TRUE)`. If you want list to be dynamic, then `excl <- c("find","during")`, then `!grepl(sprintf("\\b(%s)\\b", paste(excl, collapse="|")), words, ignore.case=TRUE)`.